# Javascript Audio playing Issue with Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a very strange problem trying to understand what is going on.
Here is my website:

www.rudybabaians.com

under "My Music" when you click on the first play-button, it plays the music, and everything is normal as expected.

The problem happens only when I try to open the website on different tabs. 
First of all, this symptom ONLY happens in Chrome. I don't see this issue neither with IE nor with FireFox.

Here is the symptom:

When I open my website on a new tab ("first" tab), and then play the music (even for one second) then everything is going to be fine. Meaning that when I go ahead and open my website on a "second" tab it will work fine. Now, when I click on the play-button on the "second" tab to play the track (even one second is enough), then it will be okay again. Meaning that when I go ahead and open my website on a "third" tab, it will work fine.
The problem **ONLY** manifests itself, if I open my website on a new tab, and then **WITHOUT** playing the music (without clicking the play button), open my website on a "second" tab. This time it will **NOT** work.
But **strangely**, it will start working under one condition, and that is when I go back to the "first" opened tab, and then play the music there (not the whole track, just a second is enough). Then come back to the "second" tab, and when I click the play button, it will work this time ?!?
It seems like somehow the track is being locked by the second instance of the website being open.
It looks like both websites trying to access the same object, and it gets confused !!!
Any idea how to fix this, or what is going on? And, more specifically, why it only happens in Chrome?

The code that I use is simply this:

In index.html:

```
<audio id="audio1"><source src="sounds/audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /><source src="sounds/audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
```

And, in JavaScript, inside "ready" function, I do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
...
        var audioElement = document.getElementById("audio1");
...    
}
```

Then, I thought that maybe I would need to define a new instance of Audio object, and I tried to use different combinations of the following lines of code:

```
var audioElement = new Audio();
audioElement = document.getElementById("audio1");
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'sounds/audio.ogg');
audioElement.load();
```

But with the above lines of codes, but again it didn't work.

Any suggestion how to fix it, please?

Thanks, 
--Rudy

Comment: sometimes with ogg file i find it best to use ovg instead. also try using more options like for mp3 etc: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Comment: I tried all the formats one by one (wav/ogg/mp3), and it is all the same behavior.